# Entity Framework Core 7 Selecting specific fields when using Include/Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-7.0

I am new to C# / .NET Core and using ASP.NET Core 7 web api and Entity Framework Core 7. When creating my GET request for the REST API resource (reviews in this example), I want to narrow down the fields I'm selecting for the entity I'm joining on using the Include() method before I send/respond to the frontend. In this example, a user can write many reviews, and a review can have one and only one user that writes the review, a one to many relationship. I want to send the reviews to the frontend with the user's data that authored the review, except the user's sensitive data.

Here is the class for the User:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? Zip { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Review>? Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

And the class for the Review:

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string? ReviewBody { get; set; }
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User? User { get; set; }
}
```

I want to GET all the reviews to send to my Angular frontend:

```
    public IEnumerable<Review> GetReviews()
    {
        return this._raineonContext.Reviews
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(r => r.User)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Obviously I don't want to send the User's password, email, and zip through the network where anyone can look at all the users that wrote reviews personal data through the network request (I know you could hash the passwords, but I don't want email or zip sent). What is the best way to SELECT specific fields I want to send to the frontend using the join/include, Id, FirstName, LastName in this case for the corresponding user.

I can't seem to find a way to do this with Entity Framework Core methods. It looks like you have to write raw SQL?

Comment: Create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) model to return the properties that needed to be shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways for your question, one is creating a new object as a new modal or use dynamic data type and copy only the fields you need to this new object and return it to frontend.  Another way is creating a [Result Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#result-filters) and set the value of Password to empty string in the filter.